# How to Replicate MySQL table from PhpMyAdmin to MySQL Workbench in different systems?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have a production system and a backup system. production system is running on Xampp server where as backup has Standalone Apache 2.4 and MySQL servers. I want to **replicate from phpMyAdmin to Workbench over LAN in real time**. PhpMyAdmin to PhpMyAdmin replication is working but to Workbench is to over a LAN.

> error connecting to master 'root@192.168.1.102:3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 11 message: Access denied for user 'root'@'username' (using password: NO) |
>   1064 |
>
> Error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by ''' at line 1' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'grant all on *.* to root@'192.168.1.102' identified by '''

Comment: **BIG NOTE** `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP to assist in easier maintenance of a MySQL database. `WorkdBench` is also a tool and Not a DBMS either. So please edit the question so that it makes abit more sense

Comment: Your workbench mySQL version differs from your PhpMyAdmin mySQL version

Comment: _PhpMyAdmin to PhpMyAdmin replication is working_ What does that really mean?

Comment: This looks like a fairly simple Account access issue. Replication can be complex, user accounts are nto anywhere near as complex

Answer (score 0):

As Noob Coder mentioned, Xampp was running Mysql 5.x while workbench was running Mysql 8.0. It was an issue of versions. Mysql 8.0 has cached SHA256 password encryption while Mysql 5.x has standard encryption and hence access denial was the case.
Thanks to RiggsFolly and Noob Coder for the mentions.

Answer (score 0):

Both PhpMyAdmin and Workbench are clients for interacting with the database. You are wrong with using the term `replicate` probably because off replication is the mechanism of DB engine, that allows having the copies of the database (slaves) being automatically updated with master data.
So to connect to DB with Workbench you need to set up a new connection. 
Credantials are:
Hostname: localhost
Port: 3306
Username: root
Password: password you set for your db in PhpMyAdmin